# React Native: Xcode error for release version of iphone. "Unhandled JS Exception: Error: A navigator cannot contain multiple 'Screen'

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, navigation, runtime-error

I'm building a react native application and previously in xcode 13 I was easily able to compile both the debug version and the release version of the app. Recently the testflight store has required a higher sdk which required me to update xcode. Since then I get this error.

```
Thread 3: "Unhandled JS Exception: Error: A navigator cannot contain multiple 'Screen' components with the same name (found duplicate screen named 'x')\n\nThis error is located at:\n    in ..., stack:\n<unknown>@628:455\nreduce@(null):(null)\n<unknown>@628:404\n<unknown>@560:2095\nyr@51:42093\nql@51:90953\nFa@51:81725\nUa@51:81627\nLa@51:81392\nEa@51:78355\nEa@(null):(null)\nft@51:26123\n_a@51:75444\nli@51:89691\n<unknown>@51:96441\n<unknown>@359:641\nrun@356:741\nrunApplication@356:1812\nvalue@38:3556\n<unknown>@38:673\nvalue@38:2503\nvalue@38:645\nvalue@(null):(null)\n"
```

I have tried deleting pods, podfile.lock, node modules, yarn package manager, and reinstalling everything. (same error occurs)
I have upgraded my node modules and dependencies to their latest versions. (same error occurs)
I have delved deep into my navigation which is rough because of the size of the application but here it is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Header from './../components/Header';
import colors from './../constants/colors';
import {
  CometChatUserProfile,
  CometChatUI,
  CometChatMessages,
  CometChatUserListWithMessages,
  CometChatUserList,
  CometChatGroupListWithMessages,
  CometChatGroupList,
  CometChatConversationListWithMessages,
  CometChatConversationList,
} from '../screens/cometchat-pro-react-native-ui-kit-3';

import {
  eventScreens,
  homeScreens,
  serviceScreens,
  fundraisingScreens,
  loginRegisterScreens as authScreens,
  newPawsScreens,
  groupScreens,
  lostPetScreens
} from '../screens/index.js'

import Video from '../screens/video/Video'

import { useAppContext } from '../components/AppContextProvider';

// ======================================================================================
// I tried to organize this code as much as possible. If you are using VS code, you can collapse 
// all of the <Stack.Group> components and find what you need so much faster. The imports are also
// cleaner and easier to read. Overall, this document is much, much smaller.
//
// If you need to add imports, just go to the individual index.js files in each /screens/* folder and add it there.
// Then, import the namespace (folder index.js) into the index.js of the /screens folder
//
// It will require a bit of refactoring app-wide, but is useful for new interns/new hires to get up to speed.
//
// 
// ======================================================================================

export function RootStack(props, { navigation }) {
  const { owner } = useAppContext()

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  function returnScreens(screenImport) {
    const options = { headerShown: false }

    const screens = Object.values(screenImport).map(screen => (
      <Stack.Screen
        name={screen.name}
        component={screen}
        options={options}
      />
    ))

    return screens
  }

  function returnHomeScreens() {
    const screensWithoutTitle = [
      "OwnerProfile",
      "FriendProfile",
      "EditProfile",
      "OwnerGallery",
      "PetGallery"
    ]

    const screens = screensWithoutTitle.map(screenName => (
      <Stack.Screen
        name={screenName}
        component={homeScreens[screenName]}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    ))

    return screens
  }

  function returnFundraiserScreens() {
    const screensWithHeader = [
      "Chewy",
      "WalkFundraising",
      "WalkFundraising2",
      "WalkSubmit",
      "WalkInvite",
      "ActiveWalk"
    ]

    const headerScreenOptions = {
      title: (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: 40 }}>
          <Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} />
        </View>
      ),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
      },
      headerTintColor: colors.White,
      headerShown: true,
    }

    const screens = Object.values(fundraisingScreens).map(screen => {
      if (screensWithHeader.includes(screen.name)) return(
        <Stack.Screen
          name={screen.name}
          component={screen}
          options={headerScreenOptions}
        />
      )

      else return(
        <Stack.Screen
          name={screen.name}
          component={screen}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: colors.White,
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      )
    })

    return screens
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={ "Login"}>
      {/* Signup / Register */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnScreens(authScreens)}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Home */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnHomeScreens()}

        {/* The rest are all different so it doesn't make sense to abstract them like we do for other screens */}
        <Stack.Screen
          name="PetProfile"
          component={homeScreens.PetProfile}
          options={{
            title: (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: 40 }}>
                <Header />
              </View>
            ),
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
            },
            headerTintColor: colors.White,
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="OwnerSettings"
          component={homeScreens.OwnerSettings}
          options={{
            title: (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: 40 }}>
                <Header />
              </View>
            ),
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
            },
            headerTintColor: colors.White,
            headerShown: true,
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="DirectMessage"
          component={homeScreens.DirectMessage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="HomeLanding"
          component={homeScreens.HomeLanding}
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
            },
            headerTintColor: colors.White,
            headerShown: false,
          }}
          initialParams={{ owner: owner }}
        />
    
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Calender"
          component={homeScreens.Calender}
          options={{
            title: (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: 40 }}>
                <Header />
              </View>
            ),
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
            },
            headerTintColor: colors.White,
            headerShown: true,
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="FriendList"
          component={homeScreens.FriendList}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: colors.White,
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Meet New Paws */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnScreens(newPawsScreens)}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Services */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnScreens(serviceScreens)}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Events */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnScreens(eventScreens)}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Groups */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnScreens(groupScreens)}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Lost/Found */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnScreens(lostPetScreens)}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Fundraisers */}
      <Stack.Group>
        {returnFundraiserScreens()}
      </Stack.Group>

      {/*  CometChat */}
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="GroupListWithMessages" component={CometChatGroupListWithMessages} />

        <Stack.Screen /// Commet Chat UI Kit
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
            "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
            "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
            "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
            "tabBarLabelStyle": {
              "fontSize": 12
            },
            "tabBarStyle": [
              {
                "display": "flex"
              },
              null
            ]
          }}
          name="CometChatUI" 
          component={CometChatUI} 
        />

        <Stack.Screen
            name="Conversation"
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
            component={CometChatConversationListWithMessages}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="ConversationComponent"
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
            component={CometChatConversationList}
          />

          <Stack.Screen name="Group" 
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
  component={CometChatGroupListWithMessages} />

          <Stack.Screen name="GroupComponent" 
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
  component={CometChatGroupList} />

          <Stack.Screen name="Users" 
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
  component={CometChatUserListWithMessages} />

          <Stack.Screen name="UsersComponent" 
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
  component={CometChatUserList} />

          <Stack.Screen name="CometChatMessages"
            options={{
          headerShown: false,
    "tabBarActiveTintColor": "#3399ff",
    "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
    "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#fff",
    "tabBarLabelStyle": {
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "tabBarStyle": [
      {
        "display": "flex"
      },
      null
    ]
  }}
  component={CometChatMessages} />
      </Stack.Group>

      {/* Video */}
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Video"
        component={Video}
        options={{
          title: (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: 40 }}>
              <Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} />
            </View>
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
          },
          headerTintColor: colors.White,
          headerShown: true,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default RootStack;
```

I do not see any duplicate screen name in the indexes either. Nor does the error reference an actual screen name only 'x' and it does not give a location of the file either.

I tried to compile my app in a release format to upload to testflight for internal testing. I expected it to work the same as the previous version of xcode but if failed and the app on the test device crashed immediately after the launch screen.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have issue with this code .   Here **screen** is not a componenet. Please Check it. or share `fundraisingScreens` Object.   you are giving an object screen to a component. Please check it again.

```
function returnFundraiserScreens() {
    const screensWithHeader = [
      'Chewy',
      'WalkFundraising',
      'WalkFundraising2',
      'WalkSubmit',
      'WalkInvite',
      'ActiveWalk',
    ];

    const headerScreenOptions = {
      title: (
        <View style={{flex: 1, maxHeight: 40}}>
          <Header style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} />
        </View>
      ),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.Primary,
      },
      headerTintColor: colors.White,
      headerShown: true,
    };

    const screens = Object.values(fundraisingScreens).map(screen => {
      if (screensWithHeader.includes(screen.name))
        return (
          <Stack.Screen
            name={screen.name}
            component={screen}
            options={headerScreenOptions}
          />
        );
      else
        return (
          <Stack.Screen
            name={screen.name}
            component={screen}
            options={{
              headerTintColor: colors.White,
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        );
    });

    return screens;
  }
```